# "You will never be the man your mother is."

Tags: meaning, interpretation

"You will never be the man your mother is" is without a doubt one of the most popular (and perhaps overused) insults. Yet I feel like I've never really grasped the true meaning it carries.

What exactly makes it so funny and offensive to so many people? Perhaps there are multiple ways of interpreting it like "why did the chicken cross the road" joke?

Comment: Personally, I've never heard that formulation of the insult, so I'm not sure I'd say it's without a doubt one of the most popular! But the point of it is clear anyway: your mother isn't even a man. Normally one says "You'll never be the man your *father* is" or "*brother*", i.e. you are not as manly or honourable as them. But by using "mother" the intended insult is intensified: even a woman is more of a man than you. Incidentally, the political correctness of the insult is probably slipping; the use of "mother" highlights the presumption that masculinity is a measure of virtue.

Comment: "without a doubt one of the most popular (and perhaps overused) insults" ← And yet, here I am, doubting away.  I've never heard it before and I can't seem to find anyone who has.

Comment: I also have never heard this insult.  That said, it is a combination of two classic insults:  _you are a female_ and  _your mother has non-feminine attributes._   Funny, right? Witticisms like this sure keep life interesting!

Comment: I think you can interpret it as having a meaning different to those given in the answers, namely that it is insulting to "your mother". It can  be a double insult.

Comment: I heard it a kind of insult (by my Chinese experience). XD. I think it means "you're a man, but like a woman, and not good enough as your mother."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I disagree with the idea that this is a "popular" or "overused" utterance, on a wide basis. But as to its meaning . . .

Simple answer:

> You are no good as a man (a failure as a man), and your mother is unwomanly (somehow mannish).
>
> You are inferior as a man and your mother is inferior as a woman.

It is an insult that implies that its target fails to meet stereotypical gender role prescriptions for masculinity. The reference to the target's mother most likely usually implies that she is also not stereotypically feminine (that she is "mannish" in some way).

Logically, it could be that the reference to a woman is at least sometimes not meant (or not interpreted to mean) anything special about the mother, but simply that the target falls so short of "being a man" that they are compared not even to another man but to a non-man.

This likely relates to, or may perhaps be mistaken for *You'll never be half the man your mother is* and variations on it.

That, in turn, seems a twist on more common expressions similar to *(someone) isn't/wasn't/will never be half the man [someone] is/was.*

It's unclear to me whether the original comparison related particularly to the idea of a masculine gender role or if *man* merely symbolized *person*, or both.

A cursory online search reveals references beginning in 2011.

There are also some examples of "Yo mama" type [maternal insult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maternal_insult) jokes:

> You Think You Strong? You'll Never Be Half The Man Yo Mama Was!

source: http://www.jokes4us.com/yomamajokes/yomamasostrongjokes.html

The song ["Hurts to Think"](https://play.spotify.com/track/07ftYx2KQvc9Wys2KYCsml?play=true&utm_source=open.spotify.com&utm_medium=open) by American singer-songwriter Miranda Lambert (2011) contains the line: *You'll never be half the man your momma is.*

Answer (score 0):

Seriously?! 
It means the woman is dependable, a go getter, a fighter for good, respected and reliable...Basically she is a leader. The qualities that are naturally expected from men & women, that he lacks.